# trivia react problemas al ingresar las preguntas de una base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Buen día, me encuentro realizando una app de trivia y no logro entender porque no se me renderizan las preguntas almacenadas en la constante 'data', este sería mi componente de trivia.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";



export default function Trivia(data, setTimeOut, numeralPregunta, setNumeralPregunta) {

  const [pregunta, setPregunta] = useState(null);
  const [respuestaSeleccionada, setRespuestaSeleccionada] = useState(null);
  const [className, setClassName] = useState('respuesta-una');

  useEffect(() => {
    setPregunta(data[numeralPregunta - 1]);
  }, [data, numeralPregunta]);


  const manejarClick = (a) => {
    setRespuestaSeleccionada(a);
    setClassName('respuesta-una active')
    setTimeOut(() => {
      setClassName(a.correct ? 'respuesta-una correcta' : 'respuesta-una incorrecta')
    }, 3000)
  }

  return (
    <div className='trivia'>
      <div className='pregunta'>{pregunta?.question}</div>
      <div className='respuestas-varias'>
        {pregunta?.answers.map((a) => (
          <div className={respuestaSeleccionada === a ? className : 'respuesta-una'}
            onClick={() => manejarClick(a)}>
            {a.text}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

y acá la app donde se encuentra alojada la constante data

```
import Trivia from './componentes/Trivia.js';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';




function App() {


  const [numeralPregunta, setNumeralPregunta] = useState(1);
  const [timeOut, setTimeOut] = useState(false);



  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      question: "Rolex is a company that specializes in what type of product?",
      answers: [
        {
          text: "Phones",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Watches",
          correct: true,
        },
        {
          text: "Food",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Cosmetics",
          correct: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: "When did the website `Facebook` launch?",
      answers: [
        {
          text: "2004",
          correct: true,
        },
        {
          text: "2005",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "2006",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "2007",
          correct: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      question: "Who played the character of harry potter in movie?",
      answers: [
        {
          text: "Johnny Deep",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Leonardo Di Caprio",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Denzel Washington",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Daniel RadCliff",
          correct: true,
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  const columnaDinero =
    [
      { id: 1, cantidad: "$ 100" },
      { id: 2, cantidad: "$ 200" },
      { id: 3, cantidad: "$ 300" },
      { id: 4, cantidad: "$ 500" },
      { id: 5, cantidad: "$ 1.000" },
      { id: 6, cantidad: "$ 2.000" },
      { id: 7, cantidad: "$ 4.000" },
      { id: 8, cantidad: "$ 8.000" },
      { id: 9, cantidad: "$ 16.000" },
      { id: 10, cantidad: "$ 32.000" },
      { id: 11, cantidad: "$ 64.000" },
      { id: 12, cantidad: "$ 125.000" },
      { id: 13, cantidad: "$ 250.000" },
      { id: 14, cantidad: "$ 500.000" },
      { id: 15, cantidad: "$ 1.000.000" },
    ].reverse();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className='contenedor-preguntas'>
        <div className='superior'>
          <div className='temporizador'>30</div>
        </div>
        <div className='inferior'>
          <Trivia
            data={data}
            setTimeOut={setTimeOut}
            numeralPregunta={numeralPregunta}
            setNumeralPregunta={setNumeralPregunta}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='columna-dinero'>
        <ul className='lista-dinero'>
          {columnaDinero.map((m) =>
            <li className={numeralPregunta === m.id ? 'item-dinero active' : 'item-dinero'}>
              <span className='numeral'>{m.id}</span>
              <span className='cantidad'>{m.cantidad}</span>
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

las preguntas de la data no rederizan y se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y pues deberían verse así en donde las respuestas puedan ser seleccionadas, la lógica para escoger una respuesta ya está implementada con los hooks correspondientes, pero no me toma la información de la data

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que el problema esta en que se esta recibiendo los parámetros de manera incorrecta en el componente `Trivia`.

`data`, `setTimeOut`, `numeralPregunta` y `setNumeralPregunta` son propiedades dentro de un objeto por lo que tienes que cambiar de:

```
export default function Trivia(data, setTimeOut, numeralPregunta, setNumeralPregunta)
```

a:

```
export default function Trivia({data, setTimeOut, numeralPregunta, setNumeralPregunta})
```